# eslint rule for preferring React Class Component syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm looking for an existing eslint rule that prefers this syntax in React Class components. Does something like this exist?

`class Foo extends Component {`

Over this:

`class Foo extends React.Component {`

Except trying to word this in a quick search is not very fruitful. Currently looking into implementing a custom rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the [no-restricted-syntax](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) rule. Try pasting this in the [demo](http://eslint.org/demo) to try it out:

```
/* eslint no-restricted-syntax: ["error", {
    "selector": "ClassDeclaration > MemberExpression.superClass[object.type='Identifier'][object.name='React'][property.type='Identifier'][property.name='Component']",
    "message": "Use `extends Component` instead"
}] */

class Valid extends Component { }

class Invalid extends React.Component { } // Use `extends Component` instead (no-restricted-syntax)
```